# UITableView - Lazy loading contact images

Tags: iphone, core-data, concurrency, uitableview, addressbook

I'm working on an iPhone application which displays thumbnail images from contacts in a UITableView.

Everything is very fast until I turn on the thumbnails, then it becomes very slow to scroll.
All the other data is backed by Core Data and I tried saving the images in Core Data beforehand, but this in itself takes too long at launch time and is less flexible etc.

What I really need is a way to do the lookup and prep thumbnails lazily with separate thread or NSOperation etc, but I'm not sure what the simplest way to accomplish this would be.

Apple's sample project LazyTableImages which is fantastic if images come from the web, could surely be adapted, although I'm having a hard time with it.   Basically the problem is the same, but instead of time lag from downloading and network latency etc,  my delay is just the time it takes to lookup the pictures in the user's address book.

This is the task in my table cell subclass I need to do concurrently:

```
        UIImage *contactImage = nil;
        if (ABPersonHasImageData(person)) {

        NSData *contactImageData = (NSData*)ABPersonCopyImageData(person);
        UIImage *tempContactImage = [UIImage imageWithData:contactImageData];
        [contactImageData release];

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(45.0f, 45.0f));             
       [tempContactImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 45.0f, 45.0f)];          
       contactImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        }
```

A big thanks to anyone who has any helpful tips or code to accomplish this in a simple and elegant way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have a UIImage, why do you need to draw into contactImage? You can just use the tempContactImage directly, no?

A good start would be to simply do this:

```
cell.imageView.image = tempContactImage
```

EDIT:

How about:

```
ABPersonRef person = ...get person...
UITableViewCell * cell = ...get cell...
[ [ NSOperationQueue mainQueue ] addOperation:
    [ NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
        if (ABPersonHasImageData(person)) {
        ...
        }
        cell.imageView.image = contactImage ;

    } ] ;
```

If that's still choppy (it may be) you can queue the images you need to apply to your table view in your background thread, wait until your table view stops scrolling, then apply any pending image changes.

Comment: If you are drawing into contactImage just to scale to fit to 45.0x45.0, you can also just use the code above and do cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill

Comment: ABPersonCopyImageData(person); 
                                CFDataRef imageData = ABPersonCopyImageDataWithFormat(person, kABPersonImageFormatThumbnail);

Comment: Thanks, but if you just use: ABPersonCopyImageData(person); You will get the full size contact image, whatever that size is. This will actually crash a table view in an iPhone app with users who have contact images in certain formats. 

Now we need to use the new much safer lower memory function: 
CFDataRef imageData = ABPersonCopyImageDataWithFormat(person, kABPersonImageFormatThumbnail);

Comment: Yes thanks, that should work. Although what I ended up doing for that project was to save all the contact data to Core Data on a background GCD queue and update it as / when needed. This allowed me to sort the records as desired and have all dates etc ready for notifications etc., regardless of the number of contacts, plus perfect silky smooth scrolling.

Comment: Don't forget: an NSManagedObjectContext is not reentrant, so you can't access simultaneously from different threads/operations. (Not saying you're doing this, just something to look out for--I was bit by this recently)

Comment: Yes, absolutely, use a separate managedObjectContext for each thread, especially since managedObjectContexts are cheap to create. There is quite a lot of complexity in synching Core Data correctly with a user's address book database, particularly due to the limited info provided by the C callback functions for ab.
But once you get it all right, multiple threads and all, it totally rocks.
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Use this method. kABPersonImageFormat**Thumbnail**

```
(NSData*)ABPersonCopyImageDataWithFormat([targetPeople objectAtIndex:index], kABPersonImageFormatThumbnail)
```